# Windows 10 x64: Intel UHD Graphics 620 8th gen forcefully turning off when on full OpenCL load

Tags: windows, gpu, opencl

**Background information:**
I have an 8th gen Intel UHD Graphics 620 which I'm doing some OpenCL computations on. These are very very complex, and can use up to 500MB of video memory. The card supposedly has 1,534 MB as reported by Windows, and this has been proven true through some Minecraft video memory tests that I did earlier.

The computer has a total of 8GB of system memory, and up to 4GB of that can be shared with the GPU. There are no dedicated GPUs.

**My issue:**
But the thing that's happening with the OpenCL stuff is that:

1. The computation starts. Cursor starts flickering a little, but the computer is usable.
2. Now the kernels are completely loaded into memory (mem less than 50% used) and the GPU starts getting used. GPU-Z shows 100% usage.
3. **Now the computer freezes. Nothing works, not even cursor movement.**
4. A few seconds later the GPU halts the computation and freezes that OpenCL program indefinitely.

Previous logs from GPU-Z show that the GPU couldn't update things like cursor position etc because it was too much under load when it was doing the OpenCL stuff.

**My question:** How can I tell a specific executable to use a limited amount of GPU power for OpenCL operations, **or** how can I tell Windows to stop putting things like cursor movement on the GPU and telling the GPU that it's okay when it's getting 100% used for OpenCL.

P.S. Temperature is not a problem. I have access to the sources for the OpenCL application, but it would be best if there would be a solution that I could apply without having to rebuild it from source.

Comment: Since the Intel GPU uses shared memory, it would be helpful, to understand the total amount of system memory the system has.

Comment: @Ramhound updated question, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

To be perfectly frank, I was trying to run a *cryptominer* on my *integrated GPU*. Oh, how young and foolish I was.

Needless to say, **I suppose this problem could *theoretically* be solved** if you told Windows somehow to use software (CPU-based) rendering for GUI elements and leave the GPU completely free. Then the GPU drivers would have no reason to halt the intense computations because if Windows leaves the GPU alone for everything other than OpenCL, there won't be any fighting for compute time.

At least that's my thought process, it's not like we can look into the Windows and Intel driver source code to check if that's exactly what happens. (*Ubuntu + Mesa* cough cough)